# Is a smiley at the end of a sentence like a period?

Tags: punctuation, emoticons

How do you treat an emoticon at the end of a sentence?

> He probably caught his cold from the kids at school :(

Should there be a period after the :(, or should I go straight into the next sentence (capitalizing the next word)?

Comment: Nice question :). I often debate putting a '.' after a smiley. I'm tempted to, but it doesn't look good IMHO.

Comment: ... or even _before_ the smiley.

Answer (score 14):

Emoticons are not used in formal writing, so how they are punctuated is really just a matter of style choice.  It depends on how you conceive of the function of emoticons.

We can think of emoticons as a **parenthetical expression** of emotion that helps the reader to understand the text (e.g., "(I feel sad.)").  In this sense, they are rather like stage directions in the script for a play.

Since emoticons are extraneous to the meaning of the sentence and can stand on their own, I would suggest only punctuating the sentence proper.

> He probably caught his cold from the kids at school. :( I hope he feels better tomorrow.

This would be roughly the equivalent of

> He probably caught his cold from the kids at school. (I feel sad.) I hope he feels better tomorrow.

If instead you feel that an emoticon instead represents **terminal punctuation** (e.g., a sad exclamation point), as some commenters have suggested, then you would leave off the period altogether since *further* punctuation is not necessary.

> He probably caught his cold from the kids at school :( I hope he feels better tomorrow.

In any case, I think it would be improper to put a period after the emoticon.

Comment: I'd add that since emoticons are a pretty new concept -- or quite possibly a passing fad -- rules for their usage are far from established.

Comment: I disagree with this - I usually see smileys replacing periods, not existing alongside them. Your example sentence with "...school. :( I hope..." looks very odd to me. I don't have any sources at hand to back this up, though, which is why this is a comment not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Having the smiley after the period looks wrong somehow...

Comment: @alcas Which is why it's a "style choice". Personally, I don't see smileys as replacing periods - that looks odd _to me_! :) IMO the period _should_ appear _before_ the smiley (never after it, as that corrupts the smiley and is potentially _wrong_ anyway).

Answer (score 7):

It entirely depends on the writer. Some use emoticons as punctuation, some don't.

However, I have never seen sentence punctuation *after* a smilie except when parenthesis (or other brackets) are being used, so I can confidently assert that doing so is *descriptively* unacceptable even if there are not yet any prescriptive rules.

In my experience, these are acceptable:

> I'm glad. :)
>   I'm glad :)
>   That's surprising news! (But I'm glad. :) )
>   That's surprising news! (But I'm glad :) )

while these are not:

> I'm glad :).
>   That's surprising news! (But I'm glad :).)

and this is acceptable, though potentially confusing as the double-parenthesis smilies have additional meanings:

> That's surprising news! (But I'm glad :))
>   That's surprising news! (And I'm sad :()

Comment: With smilies being accepted as parentheses, one will have to be careful to avoid tautology, which **I'm glad :)** seems disturbingly close to.

Comment: Yes. They're deliberately simplistic examples. :) Though, in practice, a redundant emoticon often functions as an intensifier.

Comment: That period after the emoticon sort of looks like a [mole on the chin](http://thebeautystop.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/rachel-mcadams.jpg) :^).

Comment: @J.R. That seems to be the ambiguity that makes those variations "unacceptable", yeah.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I don't know ~ after all, the mole worked for Marilyn Monroe :^.)

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that the biggest reason not to put punctuation *after* an emoticon, is so you don't inadvertently modify the emoticon itself. Emogis and other animated emoticons may not be affected, but text-based ones easily can be.

**An inane example:**

"I hope you have a good day. :) " looks totally normal.

"I hope you have a good day :). " is visually confusing. One might ask, "Is Marilyn Monroe smiling at me?"

Comment: *Emoji* is now a count noun? That’s like asking how many *kanas* or *kanjis* or *romanjis* somebody knows:  it just doesn’t sound right, at all. It’s a different class of error from *paninis* and *graffitis* and *paparazzis*, but it still sounds just as bad if not worse.