# Should emoticons be regarded as punctuation marks?

Tags: punctuation, emoticons

According to *[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation)*, “[p]unctuation marks are symbols that indicate the structure and organization of written language, as well as intonation and pauses to be observed when reading aloud”.

Does this make emoticons – when used along with a sentence, e.g., “I am good :)” – eligible to be considered as punctuation marks? They seem to satisfy the “intonation” criterion.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80928/is-a-smiley-at-the-end-of-a-sentence-like-a-period

Comment: Thanks @J.R. According to top answer there 'Emoticons are not used in formal writing'. I think that might need some justification.

Comment: @user13107: I'm curious as to why you think that statement needs justifying? Have you seen evidence to the contrary?!

Comment: @w3d: Frankly, I am not sure (though I have never seen them in formal documents, but that doesn't prove that they aren't anywhere). Is there some sort of authority on 'Formal Writing' which says so?

Comment: http://writingguide.geneseo.edu/?pg=topics/formalinformal.html

Comment: @user13107: I agree that "I haven't seen" ≠ "doesn't exist", but I think it's unreasonable to demand that the answerer present "evidence." I doubt many style guides are going to write a new chapter about emoticons, merely to inform readers to avoid them in formal writing. Moreover, how many journals do you think we should read before stating an opinion like that, looking for that lone emoticon in _Nature_ that serves as a counterargument? In this case, if you don't like the assertion, I think the onus is on you to present evidence that it's erroneous, not the other way around.

Comment: Apparently, there's as yet no canonical rule about emoticons. As no one seems to have officially declared them as marks of punctuation or members of the class, emoticons cannot presently be treated as punctuation marks. Even where they incidentally appear to serve to punctuate a sentence, maybe. The jury is still out on that one.

Comment: @ J.R. I get your point. @Kris, perhaps you should convert your comment into an answer. It seems to me that 'jury is still out' is a valid answer.

Comment: There's a very similar question on Japanese meta: [Aren't kaomoji part of the Japanese language?](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/883)

Comment: There's also a similar question on Linguistics: [Should emoticons be considered punctuation?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3359)

Comment: To me, emoticons state the feeling of the writer, and that is not a punctuation. I would write "I am good. ☺" Intonation is how pitched or loud you pronounce certain parts of a sentence, and emoticons don't add anything to that.

Comment: Another similar question on Writing: [Should an emoji come before or after a full-stop? ](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/51030/should-an-emoji-come-before-or-after-a-full-stop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, there's as yet no canonical rule about emoticons.

As no one seems to have officially declared them as marks of punctuation or members of the class, emoticons cannot presently be treated as punctuation marks. Even where they incidentally appear to serve to punctuate a sentence, maybe.

The jury is still out on that one.

---

A brief mention of interest: [Emoticons as Punctuation Marks](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=wiVz8dDW8-cC&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=%22emoticons%20as%20punctuation%22)

Comment: @mplungjan I'm able to access the page -- maybe you need Google log in to access, I'm not sure. Try http://books.google.co.in/books?id=wiVz8dDW8-cC&dq=%22emoticons+as+punctuation%22&source=gbs_navlinks_s

Comment: Now I could. I am normally always logged in to google :)

Comment: Oh, great. Do let me know.

Answer (score 9):

[Punctuation](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/punctuation%2Bmark?q=punctuation+mark):

> a mark, such as a full stop, comma, or question mark, used in writing to separate sentences and their elements and to clarify meaning.

[Emoticon](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/emoticon?q=emoticon):

> a representation of a facial expression such as a smile or frown, formed by various combinations of keyboard characters and used in electronic communications to convey the writer’s feelings or intended tone

So, no, emoticons are not punctuation, because they are not used "to separate sentences and their elements".

Comment: Does this mean that *those* emoticons that are used to separate sentences, can be considered as punctuation marks? For example, a . (full stop) is a punctuation mark, only when it is preceded by a sentence. Why can't same rule be applied for emoticons?

Comment: Emoticons aren't used to separate sentences. If they, then this is the first I've heard of it.

Comment: For example: I am glad you came :) But why are you so late? May be here again the reply might be that they are not used in formal writing. It'd be helpful if there exists an authority on formal writing which has said so and it has been documented.

Comment: It could be evolving that way. It's certainly not how I use it. I put smileys apart from any punctuation, if I'm taking the time to punctuate correctly. In *formal* writing do not use emoticons. They are not formal.

Answer (score 3):

No, an emoticon is a symbol, not punctuation. Unicode clearly differentiates symbols such as math symbols and currency symbols, from punctuation, such as open or close punctuation.

For example, these are punctuation:

```
U+0002D ‭ -  GC=Pd HYPHEN-MINUS
U+0002E ‭ .  GC=Po FULL STOP
U+0002F ‭ /  GC=Po SOLIDUS
U+0003A ‭ :  GC=Po COLON
U+0003B ‭ ;  GC=Po SEMICOLON
U+0003F ‭ ?  GC=Po QUESTION MARK
U+0007B ‭ {  GC=Ps LEFT CURLY BRACKET
U+0007D ‭ }  GC=Pe RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
U+000A1 ‭ ¡  GC=Po INVERTED EXCLAMATION MARK
U+000AB ‭ «  GC=Pi LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
U+000B7 ‭ ·  GC=Po MIDDLE DOT
U+000BB ‭ »  GC=Pf RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
U+000BF ‭ ¿  GC=Po INVERTED QUESTION MARK
```

whereas these are symbols:

```
U+000A2 ‭ ¢  GC=Sc CENT SIGN
U+000A3 ‭ £  GC=Sc POUND SIGN
U+000A4 ‭ ¤  GC=Sc CURRENCY SIGN
U+000A5 ‭ ¥  GC=Sc YEN SIGN
U+000A7 ‭ §  GC=So SECTION SIGN
U+0211E ‭ ℞  GC=So PRESCRIPTION TAKE
U+02122 ‭ ™  GC=So TRADE MARK SIGN
U+02260 ‭ ≠  GC=Sm NOT EQUAL TO
U+02261 ‭ ≡  GC=Sm IDENTICAL TO
U+02262 ‭ ≢  GC=Sm NOT IDENTICAL TO
U+02263 ‭ ≣  GC=Sm STRICTLY EQUIVALENT TO
U+02264 ‭ ≤  GC=Sm LESS-THAN OR EQUAL TO
U+02265 ‭ ≥  GC=Sm GREATER-THAN OR EQUAL TO
U+02266 ‭ ≦  GC=Sm LESS-THAN OVER EQUAL TO
U+02267 ‭ ≧  GC=Sm GREATER-THAN OVER EQUAL TO
U+02268 ‭ ≨  GC=Sm LESS-THAN BUT NOT EQUAL TO
U+02269 ‭ ≩  GC=Sm GREATER-THAN BUT NOT EQUAL TO
U+0226A ‭ ≪  GC=Sm MUCH LESS-THAN
U+0226B ‭ ≫  GC=Sm MUCH GREATER-THAN
```

And so too are all of these:

```
U+02639 ‭ ☹  GC=So WHITE FROWNING FACE
U+0263A ‭ ☺  GC=So WHITE SMILING FACE
U+0263B ‭ ☻  GC=So BLACK SMILING FACE
U+02666 ‭ ♦  GC=So BLACK DIAMOND SUIT
U+02667 ‭ ♧  GC=So WHITE CLUB SUIT
U+02695 ‭ ⚕  GC=So STAFF OF AESCULAPIUS
U+0269A ‭ ⚚  GC=So STAFF OF HERMES
U+026A2 ‭ ⚢  GC=So DOUBLED FEMALE SIGN
U+026A3 ‭ ⚣  GC=So DOUBLED MALE SIGN
U+026A4 ‭ ⚤  GC=So INTERLOCKED FEMALE AND MALE SIGN
U+026A5 ‭ ⚥  GC=So MALE AND FEMALE SIGN
U+026A6 ‭ ⚦  GC=So MALE WITH STROKE SIGN
U+026A7 ‭ ⚧  GC=So MALE WITH STROKE AND MALE AND FEMALE SIGN
U+1F430 ‭   GC=So RABBIT FACE
U+1F431 ‭   GC=So CAT FACE
U+1F432 ‭   GC=So DRAGON FACE
U+1F4A9 ‭   GC=So PILE OF POO
U+1F4AA ‭   GC=So FLEXED BICEPS
U+1F4AB ‭   GC=So DIZZY SYMBOL
U+1F607 ‭   GC=So SMILING FACE WITH HALO
U+1F608 ‭   GC=So SMILING FACE WITH HORNS
U+1F631 ‭   GC=So FACE SCREAMING IN FEAR
U+1F63A ‭   GC=So SMILING CAT FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH
U+1F63B ‭   GC=So SMILING CAT FACE WITH HEART-SHAPED EYES
U+1F427 ‭   GC=So PENGUIN
U+1F428 ‭   GC=So KOALA
U+1F429 ‭   GC=So POODLE
U+1F42A ‭   GC=So DROMEDARY CAMEL
U+1F648 ‭   GC=So SEE-NO-EVIL MONKEY
U+1F649 ‭   GC=So HEAR-NO-EVIL MONKEY
U+1F64A ‭   GC=So SPEAK-NO-EVIL MONKEY
U+1F478 ‭   GC=So PRINCESS
U+1F479 ‭   GC=So JAPANESE OGRE
U+1F47A ‭   GC=So JAPANESE GOBLIN
U+1F47B ‭   GC=So GHOST
U+1F47C ‭   GC=So BABY ANGEL
U+1F47D ‭   GC=So EXTRATERRESTRIAL ALIEN
U+1F47E ‭   GC=So ALIEN MONSTER
U+1F47F ‭   GC=So IMP
U+1F480 ‭   GC=So SKULL
U+1F71A ‭   GC=So ALCHEMICAL SYMBOL FOR GOLD
U+1F71B ‭   GC=So ALCHEMICAL SYMBOL FOR SILVER
U+1F71C ‭   GC=So ALCHEMICAL SYMBOL FOR IRON ORE
U+1F71D ‭   GC=So ALCHEMICAL SYMBOL FOR IRON ORE-2
```

Comment: Thanks @tchrist. Is that a complete list of punctuation marks? Where is ellipsis? Also I'm more interested in knowing if there is a case for emoticons being considered as punctuation marks (i.e. some kind of reasoning as to why they should/should not be considered as such).

Comment: I edited my comment above, please see.

Comment: Why? Apart from the fact that the Unicode committee didn't think so.

Comment: Sorry, if you took above comment as rude. I was just interested in whatever logic people might have applied in deciding so.

Comment: @user13107: Just my gut feeling, but I think emoticons are too new for there to be an "official ruling" on whether or not they are (or will eventually be) regarded as bona fide punctuation. I can remember emoticons making their way into e-communications, when it wasn't all that uncommon to get a follow-on email asking for an explanation after you had used one; that was only a couple of decades ago. I don't have hard evidence, and you may not like my logic 8^) but my initial posture would be that the jury's still out.

Comment: -1 Eventually, the answer fails to answer OP's one question: Are they or aren't they.

Answer (score 2):

Punctuation is a symbol.

Written language is a symbol — that is, the letters are (or were) meant to be symbols of the sound they represent.

My opinion is that emoticons are not formal, integrated punctuation symbols as yet. Check back in a hundred years or so.

Answer (score 2):

I think an emoticon is a picture. No one ever said a picture was punctuation, did they?